# writing a powershell script to relay commands over two servers

Tags: powershell

I have been working on getting a script running that runs from a main domain controller. I want to be able to run the script from this domain controller and have it invoke some commands on a varied amount of remote servers which in turn copies files from a NAS on the same network to a local directory on each server. I use credentials from a securecard that I pass in to elevate privileges but I cannot seem to get it to copy the files down unless I execute the commands on the server itself. If I can get powershell to remotely execute these commands and perform the action then I would be all set.

Here is what I have come  up with so far, please let me know what might help get this going for me. I would appreciate any help provided.

```
# Sets the variable for the source file location (c:\temp\ThisFile.exe)
#$Source = "\\nas\Applications\devapp\autononomous\v2\.exe"
$Source = "c:\temp\redirect"

# Sets the variable for the destination file location
$Destination = "temp"

# Sets the variable for application
$Application = "REDIRECT"

# Sets the variable for the remote destination file location
$Remote_Destination = "c:\$Destination\$Application"

# Sets the variable for the remote command to be executed
$Remote_Command = "regedit /s $Remote_Destination"

# Pass in the credentials you will be using to be able to copy from 
one server to another, otherwise it will attempt to use local credentials.
$Credentials = get-credential

# Read in servers from text file and execute script
$Servers = Get-Content c:\temp\PowerShell\Servers.txt | ForEach-Object {

Write-Host "Installing" $Application "on server" $_

Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination \\$_\c$\$Destination -recurse -force -Credential $Credentials

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
Param($Remote_DestinationR, $Remote_CommandR)
cmd.exe /c if not exist "c:\app\v2" mkdir "C:\app\v2"
cmd.exe /c xcopy /E /I /Y "C:\temp\redirect\home" "C:\app\v2\home"

} -Argumentlist $Remote_Destination, $Remote_Command

}
```

Comment: When `Invoke-Command` runs, what happens?  What is the issue/error?  I don't see a question or problem, as of yet, but I don't have the resources to fully test this code (as I'm not a domain admin, here).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it currently stands, this question is a bit too broad, and it might be put on hold. If you have a specific problem about this script, could you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38597845/edit) to mention that problem?